# How to import CSV to web2py Table?

Tags: python, csv, import, web2py

im new in python and web2py, im stuck in creating a form to input csv file and the code to import the csv file.

here's my simple code

MODELS = db_tables.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
db.define_table('csvfile',
                Field('nomor','integer'),
                Field('nama'),
                Field('umur','integer'),
                migrate=False,
                format = '%(name)s'
               )
```

CONTROLLER = default.py

```
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.csvfile, user_signature = False)
    response.flash = T("Hello World")
    return locals()


#def import_csv():
#    form = FORM('Value:', INPUT(_value = 'name'), INPUT(_type = 'submit'))
#    db.csvfile.import_from_csv_file(open('filename.csv'))
#    return dict(form = form)


def import_csv():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_type = 'file', _name = 'csv_file'),
             INPUT(_type = 'submit', _value = T('Import')))
    return(form=form)
```

VIEWS = default/index.html

```
{{left_sidebar_enabled,right_sidebar_enabled=False,('message' in globals())}}
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<table>
   <tr>{{=form}}
   <td>{{pass}}
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

actually i already show the table, but i cant make a form to input csv file and create a code to input the csv file with same header in 'csvfile' header

help me, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the form by using `form.process()` to actually do something with the data.

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#The-process-and-validate-methods